# Product of numbers smaller than product of average

Tags: average

I have $k$ positive numbers (actually integers) $(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$, with average $\bar x$.

I can't find a proof of the following, although I'm quite certain it is true:

$$\prod_{i=1}^k x_i \leq \bar x^k$$

For $k=2$, for any $0<\delta\leq \bar x$, I already have $$(\bar x+\delta)(\bar x-\delta) = \bar x ^2 -\delta(2\bar x-\delta)<\bar x ^2$$

There's probably a way to get the desired formula from this by applying successively to well-chosen pairs of numbers, with well-chosen $\delta$'s, but it sounds very technical for something rather intuitive.

Is there any simple way to generalize this to larger $k$? (Or maybe a direct argument?)

Any reference is welcome as well.

Comment: [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Comment: Right, $(\prod_{i=1}^k x_i)^{1/k} \leq \bar x$ ... I should have spotted this!